# Application Loader error message - supported architecture

Tags: xamarin.ios

We have an existing app in the store that pre-dates the LLVM compiler option.

When I went to upload a new version with the "LLVM optimizing compiler" switch set to "off", I received an error saying my package wasn't marked with an architecture (arm v6 or v7).  When I turned it "on" (after testing) with Arm V7, I received an error which I eventually understood to mean that I couldn't restrict compatibility for an existing app.

So I turned on both armv6/v7, which uploads fine, but results in a very large binary.

Is there a way to have the LLVM switch off, but still specify desired architecture in a way that is consistent with the older version of MonoTouch that kept the app loader happy?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable the LLVM compiler in the "iPhone build" section of the project settings. That will make MonoTouch use the original compiler, which will work just fine.

You can also turn the LLVM compiler on, and set the architecture to ARMv6. ARMv7 devices can also run ARMv6 code normally, so the code will run on all architectures.

Comment: Thanks much for your reply - much appreciated.  When I disabled the LLVM compiler, though, the AppLoader indicates that I don't have any architecture specific (or some such error message.)   Does that ring a bell ?

Comment: not really, no, sorry.. I would try to create a simple solution from scratch and submit, just to see what happens..maybe your solution is missing something? Not sure.